# Is it correct to think that these to verbs have a spatial orientation: 'pivot' and 'spin'?

Tags: meaning

... so 'pivot': is more like a rotation around the horizontal axis, whereas 'spin' - is more like around the vertical one? In what cases 'pivot' is actually used to indicate rotation, turning around?

Hello everyone! And thank you!

Comment: Please give linked and attributed dictionary definitions, including relevant example sentences. When considering astronomical bodies, one might say that spin _determines_ the 'vertical' axis.

Comment: I think of *pivot* as something an object does in a 2-dimensional plane, such as an athlete running or a car turning.

Comment: *Spin* used in the sense of *spinning wool* has no sense of orientation at all. Nor does *pivot* in the sense of having a central role.

Comment: There is a vague implication of the two different axes, but there is no "rule".  An engine "spins", while a car's front wheel, being steered, "pivots".  The main difference is that "spin" tends to be continuous in one direction, at least for a period of time, while "pivot" often implies back-and-forth motion, making significantly less than a full circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot), a **pivot** is the center point of any rotational system. The key word is *point*.

Also according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation):

> A rotation is a circular movement of an object around a center (or point) of rotation. A three-dimensional object can always be rotated about an infinite number of imaginary lines called rotation axis [sic]. If the axis passes through the body's center of mass, the body is said to rotate upon itself, or **spin**. [Emphasis mine.]

It's incorrect to think of **pivot** as meaning "more like a rotation around the horizontal axis" -- a **pivot** is a point, not an axis. It's also incorrect to think of **spin** as meaning "more like [rotation] around the vertical one" -- the axis could have any spatial orientation.

**Addendum**: As @PeterShor correctly notes in the comment below, a **pivot** can also be a shaft or a pin on which something turns. Taking that as the definition, one can still assert that a **pivot** is not "more like a rotation about a horizontal axis": the shaft or pin could be oriented in any direction in space.

For completeness, Lexico defines **[pivot](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pivot)** as follows:

> **[pivot](https://www.lexico.com/definition/pivot)**: The central point, pin, or shaft on which a mechanism turns or oscillates.

**Addendum 2**: In the above, I was focused on **pivot** as a noun, as pointed out to me by @HotLicks. As per Lexico, **pivot** as a verb means "turn on or as if on a pivot." If you take the Lexico definition of **pivot** as a noun, **pivot** as a verb means to turn or oscillate "on a central point, pin, or shaft". Again, there is no implication that the turning or oscillating is about a horizontal axis.

**Bottom line**: Neither **pivot** nor **spin** carry any implication of spatial orientation, vertical, horizontal, or otherwise.

Comment: The word *pivot* is not mentioned in the wikipedia article you cite in support of your answer. And [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivot) disagrees. "a shaft or pin on which something turns." A *shaft* is not a point.

Comment: @PeterShor Quite right. Thanks. I added an addendum to reflect the content of your comment.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, **pivot** is mentioned in the first link in my answer. I included two different links to Wikipedia.

Comment: You fail to take into account that "pivot" can be used as a verb.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

When thinking of aircraft and spacecraft, the principal axes are *pitch, yaw,* and *roll*.

> An aircraft in flight is free to rotate in three dimensions: yaw, nose left or right about an axis running up and down; pitch, nose up or down about an axis running from wing to wing; and roll, rotation about an axis running from nose to tail. The axes are alternatively designated as vertical, transverse, and longitudinal respectively.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_principal_axes))

Comment: Interesting. But OP asks about two words you don't even mention.

Comment: The OP specifically asked about spatial orientation in the title. While *spin* has a spatial orientation (*roll*), *pivot* does not. An aircraft may *bank* or *turn*, but it cannot *pivot*.

Answer (score 0):

- **spin** verb (TURN):
  to (cause to) turn around and around, especially fast:

  - *The earth spins on its axis*.
  - *The roulette players silently watched the wheel spin around/round*.
- **pivot** verb (TURN)
  to turn or twist:

  - *She pivots her left foot*.
  - *He pivoted on his heels and headed out*.
  - *Future deals will pivot on (= depend on) easing commercial conflicts*.

I think this answers my question.

Comment: Attributions and links? // But you fail to address how  "so 'pivot' is more like a rotation around the horizontal axis, whereas 'spin'  is more like around the vertical one?" is addressed here. 'He pivoted on his heels' surely doesn't involve a horizontal axis? And Uranus has an axial tilt of 97.77°, about an axis far from parallel to Earth's 'vertical'.